# Set contentEditable="true" only for the div which is clicked and false for the rest

Tags: javascript

I have many comments on a blog and an edit button on the comment.This edit button is only visible to the user who has posted that particular comment.

I have used contentEditable=true property for the div where edit button is clicked. I am facing a problem , consider below scenario for that

I as a user see a post -> then I post 3 different different comments on that post -> I can see my posted comments and individual 3 edit button.->When I click on first comment's edit button I could see that that particular comment box became editable->now when I click on other comment's edit button; that div also became editable. Hence this is the problem. I want only a single div to be editable as TRUE and rest as FALSE.Hence need to check that is there any comment box opened as editable ? If yes then make its edibility as false and true for the current one. So please let me know how can I do this.
Below are the pieces of code

MY ajax success creates below output
// --------  //

```
output+= '<button onclick="showComBox('+i+')" id="btn'+i+'" class="btn_com">EDIT</button><button onclick="update('+i+','+value.cmnt_id+')" class="done" id="done'+i+'">DONE</button>';
```

//  ---------   //
AND below is the onclick function (showComBox)

//------//

```
function showComBox(id)
    {
        var n_id = document.getElementById('cmnt_txt'+id);
        n_id.setAttribute("class" , "editable");
        document.getElementById('cmnt_txt'+id).contentEditable = "true";
        // var $div=$('#cmnt_txt'+id), isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
        // $('#cmnt_txt'+id).prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable');
        $("#btn"+id).hide();
        $("#done"+id).show();
    }
```

Comment: Store the reference to the last edited field in a variable, so that you can set it back to false for that one when you handle the next click … (Doesn’t have to be an actual reference, since you are using “numbered ids” anyway, storing the previous id/ “i” value would do as well of course.)

Comment: I also tried to do the same but not getting any idea to store the last (new to this) so that on every call of the function I can make the previous as False. Can you please direct me for this?

Comment: You store the current value at the end of your handler function, so that you have it available as the previous value in the next function call. (Needs to be a variable outside of the scope of the function itself of course, so for starters you might want to use a global variable, that can still be refined later.)

Comment: Thanks .. it helped me partially .. What left here is that if I click on an edit button make some changes to my posted comment but before saving it I click on another comment's edit button then it make editablecontent property as false for the previous one but shows the edited text; which is not correct (example "Hello" changed to "Hello All" then instead of "Hello" ; "Hello All" is visible until we refresh it). So now please help me to make the old comment as it was (I do not want to fetch it from DB again)

Comment: Well then read the original content and store it somewhere, before you enable the edit mode, so that you can simply restore it afterwards …?